# How to get the location for each GAC assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

The command "gacutil" lists only the full names without any clue about the actual location. I know the locations start at these paths:

```
 C:\WINDOWS\assembly\...
 C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\...
```

but these paths store many other assemblies and not just those in GAC. I used some C# code by calling `Assembly.Load(FullName)` or `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(FullName)` to get the object Assembly which includes location but they change the version in `FullName` to another version 
that is compatible with current runtime, e.g. when the code is compiled for `target NET Framework 4.5.2`  and if it tries to load `mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0` then it gets `mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0` instead

Comment: Why?  The whole point of the GAC is that you don't have to care about the location of the assembly.

Comment: This is part of learning process. Since assembly version is of limited use, I want to monitor the file version of each assembly in GAC,  in packages of  MVC projects, etc. Apparently, Microsoft updates them periodically and want to monitor it

Comment: Ok.  It is worth noting that .Net Core projects avoid the GAC (though that may change, I thought I heard something about the pendulum swinging the other way) - so that may be of limited utility for new projects.  You can keep up to date using NuGet (email or [RSS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/atom.xml)) or find a few good blogs and get notified there too (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/, for example)

Comment: And for something which is only to be used manually, you could also write a powershell script to parse the output of gacutil, hash each file, then do a diff.  For that matter, I think the Last Write Time for files in the GAC is the date of last change of the file on your computer - so that would be even easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate the assembly cache using COM ([`CreateAssemblyEnum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/fusion/createassemblyenum-function) → `IAssemblyEnum`, [`CreateAssemblyCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/fusion/createassemblycache-function) → `IAssemblyCache`, [`GetNextAssembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/fusion/iassemblyenum-getnextassembly-method) → [`GetAssemblyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/fusion/iassemblyname-getname-method) → [`QueryAssemblyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/fusion/iassemblycache-queryassemblyinfo-method)).

The [`QueryAssemblyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/fusion/iassemblycache-queryassemblyinfo-method) returns [`ASSEMBLY_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/fusion/assembly-info-structure) which includes the path to the assembly (`pszCurrentAssemblyPathBuf`).

There is an example of use of some of these functions at [Junfeng Zhang's MSDN blog about Sample Managed GAC API Wrappers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2004/09/14/sample-managed-gac-api-wrappers/)